# Why is java int allowed to use the | operator ? How does it evaluate?

Tags: java

I tried compiling and running the following code

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int x = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;
    //int x = 1 | 1 | 1 ;
    //int x = 1 | 2 ;
    //int x = 2 | 1 ;
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

I tried in dot net and its not working how come its working in java ?? How is this code being evaluated to produce an answer ??

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: In what unstated .NET language does OR-ing integers not work?

Comment: It's a bitwise OR operation.  3|4 = 7 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312611/operator-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is called bitwise operator in Java. It operates on the bits of the operands.The bitwise | operator performs a bitwise inclusive OR operation.

If you observer the lower order bits :

```
1 - 0001
2 - 0010
3 - 0011
4 - 0100
```

Biwise OR of each of them will produce `0111` which is `7`.You can refer to the [JLS 15.22.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1) for more.

Comment: ya right, I was confused when it couldnt compile in `dot net`. sorry :(

Answer (score 7):

```
1 | 2 = 00000001 | 00000010 = 00000011 = 3
3 | 3 = 00000011 | 00000011 = 00000011 = 3
3 | 4 = 00000011 | 00000100 = 00000111 = 7
```

Comment: I suggest to change `00000011` into `0b00000011`

Answer (score 0):

This is example of [bitwise inclusive OR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) or operator. And the result will be 7.

```
1 - 0001
2 - 0010
3 - 0011
4 - 0100
---------
7 - 0111
```

I do not know how did you used it in "dot net", but it should work. [This reading prove it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)