# what does mean these two operator "|=" and "|"

Tags: java, android

I have found this line in an application source code but i cant figure out the meaning of the bitwise or inclusive operator "**|**" between the two flags.

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

I did not also understand the meaning of this operator **|=** in the following line:

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Someone could help me plz.

Comment: Its the same as notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;  just a short form.

Comment: @RenéLink except `notification.flags` is evaluted only once.

Comment: See tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295469/what-does-mean-pipe-equal-operator

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312611/operator-in-java

Comment: People love questions that have been asked (and answered) over and over.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does |= (single pipe equal) and &=(single ampersand equal) mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942477/what-does-single-pipe-equal-and-single-ampersand-equal-mean)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd started my answer while no-one else had answered, so I decided to finish it anyway...

The pipe and ampersand `| and &` perform the `OR` and `AND` operations respectively.

You'll be used to seeing `||` and `&&`, which perform the boolean logic `OR` and `AND`, and the use of a single `| or &` is a bitwise operation.

If you look on the flag documentation, the flag for clear_top is 0x04000000, and single_top is 0x20000000.

The operation which you are performing is therefore:
0x04000000 OR 0x20000000 = 0x24000000

Which sets the required bits in the intent to use both of the desired flags.

The `a |= b` operator is the overloaded equivalent of `a = a | b`, similar to the usage of `+=`, `--` or `++`, which you should be used to seeing elsewhere

Comment: Thank you this is what i was looking for.
I already read the android doc but i did not understand but now it's better :p

Comment: Honnestly i did wrong operation i thought that 0x04000000 | 0x20000000= 0x60000000 So i did not pay attention to the position of the 4 x)

Answer (score 2):

a | b is bitwise OR of a and b.

Its the Assignment by bitwise OR

```
a1 |= a2;
```

is short for:

```
a1 = a1 | a2;
```

|= reads the same way as +=.

Answer (score 2):

Let's for assume for example that FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is 2 and FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is 4.
So in binnary the represantion will be  0000000010 for the decimal value 2 and 00000100 for the value 4. The binary or operation between those two values will give the value 6 : 00000110 (The on bits on both 2 and 4 are on) . using power of two values for suck constants will make sure thatonly unique values will come out after th bitwise or:

For example : 1 is 00000001 2 is 00000010  4 is 00000100 8 is 00001000 16 is 00010000 .....

If you are settings flags this way- it's very easy to decode the original flags : just perform a bitwise AND operation with the original flag , if it's zero than the flag is not there - if it's the flag itself - then the flag is up.

For example : let's check 000011000 for the flag SOME_FLAG - and let's say for the porpuse of the example that it's value is 8 - 00001000. After the bitwise and operation : 00011000 & 00001000 - We will get 00001000 , ANDing with something else (that does not include the flag SOME_FLAG - like any other flag with a power of 2 value) will return 0.

Comment: Sory, edited (before the edit i answered about the difference between || and | - which was not the question)

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as `notification.flags = (notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);`

cf. `a += b` is equivalent to `a = (a + b);`

where I've used the superfluous parentheses for clarity.

Comment: "*a +=b is equivalent to a = (a + b);*"? Try `byte a = 100, b = 100;`

Comment: @johnchen902; sorry I don't follow.

Comment: `a += b` is equivalent to `a = (type of a)(a + b)`. So if both `a` and `b` are `byte` (or things similiar), `a = (a + b);` raise a compile-error while `a += b` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, these are bit operators.

As Bathsheba wrote, it's equal to `(notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);`

It's an logical or, for informations see here: [Oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Infos about or at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at those flags, you will see they are all powers of two. This means exactly one bit is set to 1, so performing a bitwise or in this case does just mean to set all those flags.