# operator in Android's Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using action bar using following code,

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
 actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action);
 actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
                    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```

According to above code there is symbol/operator single vertical bar (`|`)  in method called `actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);`

so what is meaning of that single vertical bar ( | )..??

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312611/pipe-operator-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

The operator | does a "bitwise OR". The output of bitwise OR on two bits is 1 if either bit is 1 or 0 if both bits are 0. Bitwise OR on two numbers just does a bitwise OR on each bit individually.

```
Heres how 3|4 works:

  3:  00000011
  4:  00000100
--------------
3|4:  00000111 = 7
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3312647/1332870)