# Using shorter version of or "||" in an If statement with integers and Math/Logic error?

Tags: java, if-statement

So I finally got my code to work with:

```
if((choice == 1 ) || (choice == 2) || (choice == 3) || (choice == 4)){
```

but why does:

```
if(choice == (1 | 2)) {
```

result in a logic/math error? for example, if I enter "3" then the code accepts it and processes it as successful. The code snippet is as follows:

```
while(counter == 0){
        try{
            int choice = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

            if(choice == (1 | 2)){
                System.out.println("You got it!");
                ++counter;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Try again");
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException Exception){
            System.out.println("You did something wrong");
        }


    }
```

And if I do:

```
if(choice == (1 | 2 | 3 | 4 )){
```

then it will only accept 7 as far as I can tell. What exactly is going on when it is compiling and is there a way to shorten the solution I found?

Comment: Binary or `|` is different from a logical or `||`.

Comment: `|` is not a 'shorter version' of `||`, it's a different operator that does a different thing. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Comment: Google binary OR operator and all will become crystal clear. Note too that binary OR is not short-circuited.

Comment: @pvg Between booleans `|` is a non-shortcircuiting boolean OR (contrary to `||` that is a shortcircuiting boolean OR).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel not sure why you're telling me this.

Comment: @pvg Because your comment can be read as if `|` cannot take the place of `||`, but it can.

Comment: You could always make a set of the things you're checking for using the streams api and check to see if it contains your choice, (`if (Stream.of(1,2,3,4).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)).contains(choice)) { ... }`) but it's not really shorter...

Comment: @Turing85 I don't see how that question would be a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That question asks about the general difference between `|` and `||` and [from the second-highest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/96722/4216641):"*In addition, `|` can be used to perform the bitwise-OR operation on `byte`/`short`/`int`/`long` values. `||` cannot.*"

Comment: @MarkRotteveel aside from what Turing85 wrote about different types supported by both operators, even in case of boolean operands we can't always replace `||` with `|` and expect same results. If we have code like `if (a() || b()){...}` it will behave differently than `if (a() | b()){...}` if `a()` returns `true` (since `b()` will not be executed in firs case).

Comment: @Turing85 A duplicate means the **question** is a duplicate or a very near duplicate, not that one of the answers - with some mangling - also applies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pipe (|) operator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312611/pipe-operator-in-java)

Answer (score 8):

The issue here is that

```
if (choice == (1 | 2)) { ... }
```

doesn't mean "if `choice` is equal to one or equal to two, then... ." Instead, Java is interpreting `1 | 2` as "the bitwise OR of the two numbers 1 and 2," since a single vertical bar represents the bitwise OR operator. If you take the bitwise OR of 1 and 2, you get the number 3 (if you know about binary numbers, see if you can confirm why this is the case), so your if statement is completely equivalent to

```
if (choice == 3) { ... }
```

which is why you're seeing the behavior that you're seeing.

Similarly, if you write

```
if (choice == (1 | 2 | 3 | 4)) { ... }
```

Java interprets the expression `1 | 2 | 3 | 4` as "the bitwise OR of the numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4," which works out to 7.

If you have a collection of values and you want to test if a specific value is equal to any of those values, one option is, as you've noted, to have a bunch of independent equality tests. If you have a very large number of values, you may want to use something like a `HashSet` instead.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a correct and a well written answer.

Comment: This is way off-topic, but you might find [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/780210/users-by-number-of-profile-trackable-badges-obtained) interesting.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `1 | 2` is a bitwise OR, so the result is 3, and `if(choice == (1 | 2))` is actually the same as `if(choice == 3)`.

The `|` only acts as a logical OR between boolean values.

See also the Java Language Specification, [section 15.22.1 Integer Bitwise Operators `&`, `^`, and `|`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1):

> When both operands of an operator `&`, `^`, or `|` are of a type that
>   is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive integral type, binary numeric
>   promotion is first performed on the operands (§5.6.2).
>
> The type of the bitwise operator expression is the promoted type of
>   the operands.
>
> [..]
>
> For `|`, the result value is the bitwise inclusive OR of the 
>   operand values.

and [section 15.22.2 Boolean Logical Operators `&`, `^`, and `|`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2)

> When both operands of a `&`, `^`, or `|` operator are of type
>   `boolean` or `Boolean`, then the type of the bitwise operator
>   expression is `boolean`. In all cases, the operands are subject to
>   unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) as necessary.
>
> [..]
>
> For `|`, the result value is `false` if both operand values are
>   `false`; otherwise, the result is `true`.

As to a shorter solution, trivially your initial code is probably as simple as it can get. If you want to scale it to a larger number of conditions, then consider:

- `1 <= choice && choice <= 4` - if accepted values of choice are a contiguous range
- `Arrays.binarySearch(new int[1, 2, 3, 4], choice) >= 0` - requires that the array is sorted
- `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4).contains(choice)` - this has overhead, because this converts the integer values to objects.
- Convert your code to a switch (not immediately shorter, until we get pattern-matching switch in a future Java version, but can be clearer with a lot of values)

  ```
  switch(choice) {
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
  case 4:
      // if 1, 2, 3, 4
      // do things
      break;
  case 5:
      // else if 5
      // do other things
      break
  default:
      // else
      // do something else
      break;
  }
  ```

Except the first and the last, these options have the downside that it is not immediately clear what you are checking for. In those case, clear code trumps 'short' code.

Comment: Downvoter, please leave an explanation? Do you think this is too short, or did I post something factually incorrect?

Comment: It's a trivial dupe.

Comment: @pvg of which question, I tried a quick google search, but I did not find one quickly that covered this question.

Comment: Well if it’s a trivial dupe then vote to close as such. That ought not to motivate anyone to downvote answers.

Comment: The dupe is in the comments. You should vote to close this as such.

Comment: @pvg And that wasn't a duplicate of this question, that was about the difference between full logical OR and short-circuiting logical OR.

Answer (score 0):

`|` is not a shorter version of `||`.
`|` is a bitwise inclusive OR operator.

In this the logic result `1` if any one of bit value is 1. The result will be `0` only if both the values are `0`.

for `(1 | 2)` for example, it gives in binary form : 
  `0 ... 0 0 1` 
`0 ... 0 1 0`

Applying the rule it produces :
`0 ... 0 1 1` -> `3`

About how to simplify that :

```
if((choice == 1 ) || (choice == 2) || (choice == 3) || (choice == 4)){
```

First, parentheses between each comparison are not required as `==` has higher precedence than `||` :

```
if(choice == 1  || choice == 2 || choice == 3 || choice == 4){
```

Second, as acceptable values are contiguous, the most simple way is  :

```
if(choice >= 1  && choice <=4){
```

Note that you could also a `Set` or a `List` that contains acceptable values in no contiguous cases :

```
if (Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4).contains(choice)){
     ...
}
```

or use an `IntStream` :

```
if (IntStream.range(1,5).anyMatch(i-> i == choice)) {
 ... 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

| does binary or that is different from logical ||.

```
1|2 = 01|10(binary representation) = 11(binary) = 3(base10)
```

if you want to apply shortcut then this will help

```
if(choice|((2<<1)+(2<<2)+(2<<3)+(2<<4))) {
...
}
```

Comment: You do know that `^` is the bitwise-XOR?

Comment: No, `^` is NOT the power function. If you want the `n`-th power of `2`, use `2 << (n - 1)`, where `n` is the power and `1<= n <= 64`